# Returing a single boolean value if value is duplicated in pandas series?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Given the following pandas DataFrame:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame([{'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-09-2014', 'Spend': 1.34, 'Clicks': 241}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Y', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 2.89, 'Clicks': 12}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 1.20, 'Clicks': 1}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Z2', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 4.56, 'Clicks': 13}] )
```

[image]

I simply want to check (and return a *single* boolean value) if a given campaign appears more than once.

I could do:

```
True in mydf['Campaign'].duplicated().get_values()
```

or:

```
True if len(mydf.drop_duplicates('Campaign')) < len(mydf['Campaign']) else False
```

Is there a better/more efficient way? If not, which of the above is preferable?

Comment: Run each method with %timeit in IPython and see which performs best and if neither then use the shortest one unless its obscure which is not the case in this example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first proposed method is the fastest on a small dataframe.

```
%timeit mydf.Campaign.duplicated().any()
The slowest run took 4.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.9 µs per loop

%timeit True in mydf['Campaign'].duplicated().get_values()
The slowest run took 4.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 µs per loop

%timeit True if len(mydf.drop_duplicates('Campaign')) < len(mydf['Campaign']) else False
1000 loops, best of 3: 311 µs per loop
```

On a larger dataframe, however, my method (the first one below) is slightly faster.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 1e6, replace=True), 'Date': pd.date_range('2015-1-1', periods=1e6), 'Spend': np.random.randn(1e6), 'Clicks': np.random.rand(1e6)})

%timeit mydf.Campaign.duplicated().any()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop

%timeit True in mydf['Campaign'].duplicated().get_values()
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop

%timeit True if len(mydf.drop_duplicates('Campaign')) < len(mydf['Campaign']) else False
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop
```